# Detect specific tag with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text:

```html
<:Hello
 World
:>

Blah Blah Blah

<:Hello
 Foobar
:>
```

And i want to match every `<:Hello ... :>` Tag with a regular expression (In JavaScript). So what's supposed to be matched is `World` and `Foobar` but not `blah blah blah`.

I tried using
`/<:HELLO([\s]{1,})([\s\S]{1,})?:>/gi`
But it matches the whole text From the first `<:Hello` to the last `:>`
How can i match each tag separately?

Comment: How can `PINEAPPLE` match `Hello`?

Comment: `[\s\S]{1,}` = `[\s\S]+` => too *greedy*. Solution: as usual, add `?` after `+`. And remove `?` after `)` as it makes the group optional.